# React jQuery AJAX global caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, caching

I am developing React application and for frontend AJAX requests I use jQuery, but I want to cache my requests like angular `http.get(url, {cache: true })` does.
Is there any way which can help me do this global caching for GET requests.
I tried to add `cache: true` property to request but it seems not working.

For example my code looks like this

```
$.ajax(source, {
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
        c: count,
        p: period
    },
    cache: true,
    success: (response) => {

    }
})
```

I have tried also

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:true
});
```

for all requests, but unfortunatley I can see request under Chrome devtools network tab, as well as in my server logs.
So I want to prevent from doing same request if data and url is same.
I can create some storage myself, but I think there should be default way for doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use $.get() it has cache:true.

Comment: but `cache: true` is not working, I can see requests in devtool network tab, as well as in my server logs

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be checking if the last request data are the same than the current.

```js
var lastRequestedData = {};
function myAjaxRequest(requestData) {
    if (JSON.stringify(requestData) != JSON.stringify(lastRequestedData)) {
        lastRequestedData = requestData;
        alert('Makes the ajax request: '+ JSON.stringify(requestData));
        //$.ajax(...)
    }
}

myAjaxRequest({"c":1,"p":2}); // Fire
myAjaxRequest({"c":1,"p":2}); // Not fire
myAjaxRequest({"c":2,"p":3}); // Fire
```